# Can we say “the school will take the students to...?”

Tags: word-choice

“The school will take the students to the zoo.”

Is it correct to say this or is it a bit weird? This is comprehensible, but a school cannot physically take someone from a place to another. Is it more appropriate to say “The teachers will take the students to the zoo”?

Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of compromises like that in English. Because the meaning is clear, you can overlook the technicalities. It depends on context, though. You could say that our school regularly visits the zoo, but if you're talking at length about a specific visit, it might be better to start getting more specific about who actually took the children to the zoo.

Comment: Of course. Amopng the definitions of "school," "a building housing a school" is seven down. The top definition of "school" (the one used for "school" in that seventh definition) is "an institution for instruction." An "institution" is "an organization, establishment, foundation, society, or the like, devoted to the promotion of a particular cause or program, especially one of a public, educational, or charitable character." An organization is people. A society is people. So an institution is people. So a school is people. A school is people first and foremost, the building coming in seventh.

Comment: The sentence in the question's header lacks a "will" which is in the sentence in the question's body.

Comment: This is an example of metonymy, and like say 'the kettle is boiling', is clearly understood (although context is, as always, needed). I'd say your example is a little unusual (unless all the school's students are involved); I'd expect the passive instead.

Comment: It's a metaphor. Don't worry about it being literal.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to say “The school will take the students to the zoo.” The meaning is clear.

Examples to that: "the White House will send greetings...", "Moscow will introduce...", etc.

There is no question to that, and “The teachers will take the students to the zoo.” doesn't make it any better.

So, you can choose whichever you want.